# Замена последней буквы e в слове с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Код заменяет с помощью регулярного выражения последнюю букву 'e' в слове, если слово не состоит только из буквы 'e'. При этом после слова может стоять любой знак препинания.

```
...
Regex r = new Regex(@"[a-z]{1,}e\W", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection items = r.Matches(s_text);
//Замена
foreach (Match i in items)
{
   string line = i.ToString();
   string newLine;
   newLine = line.Remove(line.LastIndexOf('e'), 1);
   s_text = Regex.Replace(s_text, line, newLine);
}
...
```

На примере Bonoparte), возникает исключение

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: parsing 'Bonoparte)' - Too many )'s.
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.ScanRegex()
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.Parse(String re, RegexOptions op)
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex..ctor(String pattern, RegexOptions options, TimeSpan matchTimeout, Boolean useCache)
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(String input, String pattern, String replacement)
   at ConsoleApp2.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Arianttel\source\repos\ConsoleApp6\ConsoleApp6\Program.cs:line 98
```

Если поставить пробел перед скобкой, то все работает.

Comment: вторым параметром в [Replace](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_) передается `pattern` - который парсится как регулярное выражение, и так как `Bonoparte)` - не корректное регулярное выражение - происходит указанная ошибка

Comment: @Grundy, тогда возможно ли в данном случае обработать слова после которых идут скобки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте *захватывающую группу*, а также можно и *границу слова*:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"([a-z])e\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
s_text = r.Replace(s_text, "$1");
```

Или просто

```
s_text = Regex.Replace(s_text, @"(?i)([a-z])e\b", "$1");
```

См. [демо-код онлайн](https://ideone.com/eYJE2T):

```
var s_text = "Bonaparte)";
Regex r = new Regex(@"([a-z])e\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
s_text = r.Replace(s_text, "$1");
Console.WriteLine(s_text); // => Bonapart)
```

**Подробности**

- `([a-z])` - Захватывающая подмаска/группа №1: буква ASCII
- `e` - буква `e`
- `\b` - граница слова.

`$1` является обратной ссылкой на значение в захватывающей подмаске №1.